# find an element inside an array element of an array of elements and replacing it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to look for issueDate inside my array of arrays and if it exists then I want to replace it with Issue Date.

```
myArr = [
    ["Application", "123"]
    ["Status", "Completed"]
    ["Address", "1 fake st"]
    ["issueDate", "2018/07/02"]
    ["Unit", null]
]
```

So the result array should look like this:

```
myArr = [
    ["Application", "123"]
    ["Status", "Completed"]
    ["Address", "1 fake st"]
    ["Issue Date", "2018/07/02"]
    ["Unit", null]
]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried:
var index = myArr.indexOf("issueDate");
myArr[index] = "Issue Date";
But it doesn't work since each array has an array as an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find() and update the first index

```js
var myArr = [
    ["Application", "123"],
    ["Status", "Completed"],
    ["Address", "1 fake st"],
    ["issueDate", "2018/07/02"],
    ["Unit", null],
]

myArr.find(x => x[0] === "issueDate")[0] = "Issue Date";

// myArr.find(function(x) { return x[0] === "issueDate"})[0] = "Issue Date";


console.log(myArr);
```

If it may not be there

```js
var myArr = [
    ["Application", "123"],
    ["Status", "Completed"],
    ["Address", "1 fake st"],
    ["issueDate", "2018/07/02"],
    ["Unit", null],
]

// var item = myArr.find(function(x) { return x[0] === "issueDate"});

var item = myArr.find(x => x[0] === "issueDate");
if (item) item[0] = "Issue Date";

console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: I get the error: "Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined""

Comment: my code assumes it is there. If it can not be there it is one extra line Altered the code with the if check.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
let myArr = [
    ["Application", "123"],
    ["Status", "Completed"],
    ["Address", "1 fake st"],
    ["issueDate", "2018/07/02"],
    ["Unit", null]
];

for(let arr of myArr){
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] === "issueDate"){
      arr[i] = "Issue Date";
    }
  }
}
console.log(myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the map to modify content in an array

```js
const myArr = [
    ["Application", "123"],
    ["Status", "Completed"],
    ["Address", "1 fake st"],
    ["issueDate", "2018/07/02"],
    ["Unit", null]
];

const newArr = myArr.map(a => {
    const tempArray = a;
    if (tempArray[0] === "issueDate") {
        tempArray[0] = "Issue Date";
    } 
    return tempArray;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  ["Application", "123"],
  ["Status", "Completed"],
  ["Address", "1 fake st"],
  ["issueDate", "2018/07/02"],
  ["Unit", null],
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (cur[0] === "issueDate") {
    acc.push(["Issue Date", cur[1]]);
  } else {
    acc.push([...cur]);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have permission to transform this array into an object?

It will be easier to do the checks

Example:

```
const myArr = [
  { "Application": "123" },
  { "Status": "Completed" },
  { "Address": "1 fake st" },
  { "issueDate": "2018/07/02" },
  { "Unit": null },
]
```